Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot is stuck
Dual boot of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows is not working, after boot up display Ubuntu 22.04 screen. After that this screen appears and nothing happens after that.


What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Did you install a proprietary driver if you have nVidia? Is UEFI Secure Boot on? Are you dual booting with Windows?

@oldfred Device : Dell Inspiron 15 3520, 12Gen intel i5-1235U 1.30 GHz, 16GB RAM, intel iRISXe graphics, Secure Boot : Enabled, Yes Dual boot windows 10 + ubuntu 22

You may need 24.04. I have similar Dell but 11th Gen & it works well with 24.04. I had dual boot, but Dell had to replace motherboard & Ubuntu still worked, but Windows did not. Windows repairs did not work, so end up with total Dell recovery install which erased Ubuntu. I now use external SSD for Ubuntu and rarely boot Windows. Or once you get connected, make sure you have good backups. And Backup Windows now.

@oldfred The device is HP Laptop 15-db0170AU AMD E2-9000e RADEON R2 4 COMPUTE CORSE 2C+2G 1.50GHz, I mistook with my other device.

HP's have some unique requirements. Primarily to change boot order in UEFI settings after install. Some settings: Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2 &
https://www.phoronix.com/news/HP-BIOSCFG-For-Linux-6.6
May have similar settings since HP. HP Zbook 15 NVRAM locked, install issues multiple settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555

@oldfred, I have just tried boot repair tool, I have follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair, but still same issue, here is the generated report's link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cmPdYpgGvt/

Have you changed boot order in HP's system settings F9 to have "ubuntu" entry first in boot order? Does Ubuntu boot ok when manually selected from one  time boot menu F10. Report does not show any errors. The modprobe error is not a valid error.
